# How to fix WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER when making API calls with Python?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I have a pyspark environment in which I'm trying to run a python script to make an API call. This is my code:

```
proxy = {
    "http": "http://proxy_url:port",
    "https": "https://proxy_url:port"
}
proxy_auth = requests.auth.HTTPProxyAuth("username", "password")
token_value = "access_token"

url = "https://host/endpoint/"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {token_value}"}
data = {"id": "123456", "type": "ALL"}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, proxies=proxy, auth=proxy_auth)
print(response.json())
```

When I try to run the above code I get the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /endpoint/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /endpoint/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

The environment has python version 3.7.3 and requests version 2.26.0. If I add all those configurations (including the proxy ones) in Postman, I can make the request just fine, the issue only happens when I make the calls through python script.

Comment: In short: wrong settings for the HTTPS proxy - it should be accessed with `http://` not `https://`